# Xcode - Dealing with folders by code

Tags: xcode

When you add a folder that contain subfolders and files to the Xcode project, the Xcode ask you about the folder option:

1. Create groups for any added folders.
2. Create folder references for any added folders.

I want to download the folder from a server. When the download is complete, the folder option will be 1 or 2? How can I set the folder option to option 2?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you trying to get Xcode to automatically import these folders you're downloading? Or are you trying to have your own app do something with folders that are downloaded?

Comment: I'm using a KRPano Library for panorama view, when i produce a set of image, it get with a number of file's and folder's, and when importing it to the xcode, i've to check the "Create folder references for any added folders.", does this applied to any downloaded file, i mean by downloaded is put the same file in a server and download it to the app to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Xcode references a folder, it uses whatever files are stored at that location on your local disk. If you download a new file to that folder or copy a file into that folder, it will show up in your Xcode project. If you change a file in that folder (by overwriting it in the Finder, or by using another app to download another copy of the file over the existing one), Xcode will use the new one.